Why is zabbix agent running on Zabbix server able to see connection requests from foreign hosts?
My Zabbix server has Zabbix agent running on it. Zabbix is monitoring Zabbix. Good.
Why would the agent listening only on 127.0.0.1 be able to receive connection attempts from a remote host? That is the job of the Zabbix server daemon, not the agent daemon, right?
My /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log is filling up with this error.
failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "192.168.10.2" rejected, allowed hosts: "127.0.0.1"

Yes, 192.168.10.2 is a host I am monitoring.
Here is my zabbix_agent.conf file.
PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=0
Server=127.0.0.1
ServerActive=127.0.0.1
Hostname=Zabbix server
HostnameItem=system.hostname
Include=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/*.conf


When I set
ListenIP=127.0.0.1
and restarted the agent daemon, the error messages ended.
I guess I should blame the Zabbix package maintainer for this. It's a really dumb default.
